# how to catch for/while statement with clang in python

Tags: python, clang, llvm-clang

I calculate C/C++ code's cyclomatic complexity with clang in python module.

And, I caught almost statement but, I can't catch several statement that don't

have a brace.

example, if below statement can catch and calculate cyclomatic complexity.

```
if (i == 1 && k ==2)
{
    cout << 'q' << endl;
}
```

but, below statement can't catch.

```
if (i == 1 && k ==2)
    cout << 'q' << endl;
```

please, tell me how to catch that statement.

Comment: Could you provide a  bit more detail about what you're doing and what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only block I can think of that is not necessarily brace-enclosed (except for `goto` but we won't go in to that) would be the `case`s of a `switch`/`case` block. In that case you could check for delimiters. Unlike python, you don't have indentation check. So either the block has one line of code or it is brace-enclosed.

To add extra ugliness, do you currently check for lines like

```
if (my_condition_1) ++x;
else if (my_condition_2) --x;
```

?

Yes, they're ugly, and you'll usually be quickly poo-pooed out of doing one of these. But nevertheless, coding styles like that are possible.

*(All suggestions under the condition that I understand correctly what kind of information you're trying to get. +1 for the clarification request)*